# Azure private AKS enable outbound access to internet

Tags: azure, azure-aks

On Azure I placed private AKS cluster with private LoadBalancer (LB).

From any pod (I have only deployment and service with private IP using private LB, no ingress etc) I can't access any site from public internet, and I need to do it avoiding Azure Firewall that is too expensive

Which resources can help me to enable outbound access without making private cluster public?

Comment: Do you consider to use Public IP for outbound traffic(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress-outboundtype#outbound-type-of-loadbalancer) or NAT Gateway? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/nat-gateway

Comment: @AndriyBilous private(internal) AKS LB can be used to forward traffic to egress public IP? Or I need second (public) LB?

Comment: I assume you do not have Public IP yet, so you can use new public IP with az aks update command with the load-balancer-outbound-ips parameter to update your cluster with your public IP.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/load-balancer-standard#update-the-cluster-with-your-own-outbound-public-ip

See also https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11484